# cmd.exe process doesn't stop when c# program ends

Tags: c#, cmd

I have a c# program that can launch another program by creating a process for cmd.exe and starting it with the arguments to start the program.  This works great.  However, when the c# program terminates, the cmd.exe process does not stop.  So if I run the program 5 times, there are 5 cmd.exe processes open still.

Do I need to explicitly shutdown the process?  The process may not always be open, so I'm not sure the best way to do this.  My intention by using the 'using' statement was so that the cmd.exe process would be released when it was done.

```
                using (Process cmd = new Process())
            { 
                cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                cmd.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                cmd.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                cmd.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(SimProperties.dbJarPath);
                cmd.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format("{0} {1} {2} {3} {4} {5} {6} {7} {8} {9} {10} {11}",
                    "/k",
                    "java",
                    "-Xms2048m",
                    "-Xmx2048m",
                    "-XX:NewRatio=3",
                    "-Xss1024m",
                    "-XX:+UseParallelGC",
                    "-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=100",
                    "-XX:ParallelGCThreads=9",
                    "-jar",
                    SimProperties.dbJarPath,
                    SimProperties.dbScenarioPath);

                cmd.Start();
            }
```

Comment: why do you have to use `cmd`?

Comment: Also, what's the point of all those hard-coded arguments? Why not pass the entire command at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens is that your cmd.exe executes the command (the java console) and then returns to the command prompt.

CMD /K    Run Command and then return to the CMD prompt.

https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html

Try `CMD /c` instead.

You can also run the java console without invoking the console. Instead of:

```
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
```

try

```
cmd.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\...full path to your java...\java.exe";
```

Comment: Perfect.. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

`cmd.exe` is a different process from your application, hence you need to free it explicitly.
 you can kill all cmd process like this:

```
Array.ForEach(Process.GetProcessesByName("cmd"), x => x.Kill());
```

its possible to execute this line with in the closing event of your application.

Comment: Kills all running cmd processes on the computer. Not only  the one your running

Comment: So find your specific process by GetProcessById().

Comment: doesn't say that :)